# "Hibernating" service fabric application

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have a kinda small service fabric application that I'm building and have since I converted to service fabric been annoyed about the slow startup time and it's not only after a release but also after like 10-15 min of inactivity.

I have added a project whose sole purpose is to go to each service and make a small db request every 10s, thinking that will keep the application and ef running. This helped me from getting timeouts and now the first requests are in the 5-15s range. After some warming up the requests are usually in the 300ms range so they are quite easy requests and there isn't much communication between the services (4 services in total).

After a lot of searching I found a profiler that seems to work as most doesn't like the one in visual studio. Unfortunately it didn't really say that much except that it waits for threads a lot and that it doesn't seem to be in my code. All my external requests use await async. Also when following the request it kinda seemed like there were information missing...

At first I thought that the slowness might come from ef generating the search query so I migrated that part to use dapper instead (the full request still uses some ef) but that didn't change anything really.

The application has all the latest service fabric, dotnet core, ef core, application insights packages. All services except for the one validating tokens are stateless. And of course built in release mode.

At this point I'm kinda lost as I cannot find the reason it's so slow. In the old days this was usually because of IIS shutting down the application or recycling it but now when it isn't there, what can it be?

Comment: Are you deploying this to a cluster in Azure or are you just experiencing this on your local machine?

Comment: Im having this problem both locally and when deploying it to a 3 server cluster, which isnt in azure

Comment: Assuming your traffic is load balanced... Do some logging on which node your service resolves to. It could be that request 1 goes to node A (15s response), 2 to node B (15s response), 3 to node A (now 300ms response), 4 to node C (15s response). See what I'm getting at?

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue happen to us however we use DI container and until the first call to our service, all dependency is not resolved and it take time to create these instances. For example a singleton of class. Another one is was EF DB context. To overcome that we have process to "warm" the services first.

Hope that helps

Comment: This doesn't answer why his applications are going to "sleep" after a few mins!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a shot in the dark: Are your services communicating using the Service Fabric remoting options or using HTTP? In the case of HTTP, might the hibernation and warmup time be caused by HttpSys/Kestrel?

Regarding your slow responses (300ms) that does seem a bit odd, we have multiple stateless services (using HTTP and Kestrel) with EF in the back, and have sub 50ms response times).